# Fail to send mail from AWS-ECS container, not getting any error?

Tags: email, amazon-ecs, nodemailer

Our node application is not able to send mail from ECS cluster. Right not running docker container on ECS cluster and one of our functionality trying to send mail using "nodemailer" node module to the users but it it not able to send mail.
Here is the snippet which we are using,

```
*const sender = 'no_reply@xyz.com';
let transporter = mail.createTransport({
host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 587,
secure: false,
auth: {
user: 'no_reply@xyz.com',
pass: 'password123'
},
});*
```

Even, tried by opening outgoing port on security group still facing same issue.
Please help solving issue.

Thanks,
Amol

Comment: "Not able" is imprecise. What happens when you run that snippet? Do you get an error? What's the error? See: For more advice on how to write a good question, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @GeoffreyWiseman Updated the question. Also, not getting any error related to mail functionality.

Comment: No errors at all? So when you say "not able to send mail" you mean "the mail doesn't arrive"? Where's the actual send call in your snippet? Are you implementing the call-back and checking the err parameter?